# If $\,ax+b=cx+d,\,$ then is $\,a=c\,$ and $\,b=d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am a high school student my maths teacher said that if $\,ax+b=cx+d,\,$ then is $\,a=c\,$ and $\,b=d.\,$ Can someone give me a prove of this?

Comment: This is false. For example if x = 0 only c and d need to be equal, and a and b can be anything.

Comment: In the context of polynomials what your teacher meant to say is that if, for all real values of $x$ it is the case that $ax+b=cx+d$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: Wrong statement

Comment: @Vik78 Think you've got your coefficients slightly mixed up; I know what you mean but you've had a slight typo there. You mean in the context of $x=0$ that $a$ and $c$ can be anything...

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=0$, then $b=d$. So $ax+b=cx+b$. So $ax=cx$. Then let $x=1$ to get $a=c$

Answer (score 2):

The statement "ax + b = cx + d implies a=c and b = d" is not true and should be obviously so.  Simply do $b = cx + d - ax$ and you get $ax + b = ax + cx + d - ax = cx + d$.  $a, b, c$ and $x$ can be anything you like.

That's silly.

**HOWEVER** the statement "ax + b = cx + d *for all possible values of x* (where x is not a constant) implies a=c and b = d" **is** true.

Pf:

$ax + b = cx + d \iff$

$(a-c)x = d - b$.

$d- b$ is a constant value.  If $(a-c)\ne 0$ then $(a-c)x$ can have multiple values for different values of $x$.  As $(a-c)x$ is constant for all possible values of $x$, the only way this is possible is if $(a-c)  = 0$ i.e. a = c.

But then $(a-c)x = d-b \implies 0x = 0 = d-b \implies b = d$.

(I *can't* say: Let $b = cx + d - ax$ as $cx +d -ax$ will have different values for different values of $x$.  ... unless $c =a$ ... in which case I'm saying "Let $b = d$"....)

Comment: In fact, we don't need "for all possible values of $x$" ... we only need "for two different values of $x$".

Comment: @GEdgar   True. $$

Answer (score 0):

By the fundamental theorem of algebra (FTA), a first degree polynomial has exactly $1$ root.  Thus if there are $2$ or more values of $x$ for which the equation holds, then $(a-c)x+(b-d)$ is the zero polynomial.   So $a=c$ and $b=d$.